# C++ adding headers in class is killing me

Tags: c++

I've to include another class file into my `.h` file but it keeps giving me strange error.

It's not picking up the `vector` class. I've mentioned error on the line I am getting. It says `vector is not a Template`. I also tried to include `<vector>` library in the `.cpp` file but it's not working.

**My MidPointRelations.cpp:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MidPointRelations.h"

MidPointRelations::MidPointRelations()
{

}


MidPointRelations::~MidPointRelations()
{

}



MidPointRelations::MidPointRelations(MyLines line, float midpointdis, float aspect)
{
    mylinesss.push_back(line);
    midpointDistance = midpointdis;
    aspectratio = aspect;
}

float MidPointRelations::getAspectRatio(){ return aspectratio; }
void MidPointRelations::Add(MyLines line)
{
    mylinesss.push_back(line);
};

vector<MyLines> MidPointRelations::getLines()  //<<----- error
{
    return mylinesss; 
}

float getMidPointDistance() 
{
    return midpointDistance; 
}
```

**My MidPointRelations.h:**

```
#pragma once
#include "MyLines.h"
#include <vector>
class MidPointRelations
{
private:
    std::vector<MyLines> mylinesss;
    float midpointDistance;
    float aspectratio;

public:
    MidPointRelations(MyLines line, float midpointdis, float aspect);
    MidPointRelations();
    ~MidPointRelations();
    float getAspectRatio();
    void Add(MyLines line);
    std::vector<MyLines> getLines();
    float getMidPointDistance();
};
```

Comment: Should be `std::vector`

Comment: BTW: If the tutorial doesn't teach about `std`, it isn't worth your time, unless you are a historian (spelling?).

Answer (score 2):

Simple typo: replace vector with std::vector

You can write 'using std::vector', or even 'using namespace std' and thereafter use just vector, but that can cause namespace pollution. I'd certainly recommend you don't do that in headers.